# wpf access to subfolder

Tags: wpf, image, subdirectory

Hi I have litlle problem with access to images in folder. My project has this folder structure:

- **Views (folder)**

  - SomeView.xaml
- **Images (folder)**

  - **Icons (folder)**

    - some.ico

In SomeView.xaml I would like set some.ico as source for Image control.

Something like this:

```
                    <Image Source="images\icons\menu\some.ico" Height="20"/>
```

But it search for ico file ine *`Views/Images/Icons/some.ico`*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an absolute URI instead of a relative one, e.g.:

```
"pack://application:,,,/YourAssemblyName;Component/images/icons/menu/some.ico"
```

A style issue, but use forward slashes. The address is a URI, not a Windows file path.

Comment: It is working as charm. But why it is searching in "Views/Images/Icons/some.ico" folder. The absolute Uri is lengthy to give in all places.